# Вывод в запросе заданного вида SQL

Tags: sql

Есть справочник допустимого времени посещения офиса клиентами: `t_time_table` с колонками

- id_time (int),
- name (varchar),
- sort (int).

Содержит данные типа

```
(1, ‘9:00’, 0),
(2, ‘9:15’, 1),
(3, ‘9:30’, 2),
(4, ‘9:45’, 3),
(5, ’10:00’, 4)
```

Последняя колонка – сортировка, числа идут строго по порядку с шагом 1.

Как вывести все посещения в запросе вида: время начала сеанса, время окончания (совпадает с началом следующего сеанса)?

Как вывести последний сеанс?

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД, включая версию.

Comment: *Как вывести последний сеанс?* Никак - время его окончания взять тупо неоткуда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как вывести все посещения в запросе вида: время начала сеанса, время окончания (совпадает с началом следующего сеанса)?

```
SELECT
  t1.id_time,
  t1.name as start,
  t2.name as stop
FROM
  t_time_table t1
  LEFT JOIN t_time_table t2 ON (
    t2.sort = t1.sort + 1
  )
ORDER BY
  t1.sort;
```

запрос работает только при условии

> сортировка, числа идут строго по порядку с шагом 1.

---

> Как вывести последний сеанс?

```
SELECT
  t.id_time,
  t.name
FROM
  t_time_table t
WHERE
  t.sort = (SELECT MAX(sort) FROM t_time_table);
```

Для MySQL последний запрос можно переписать так

```
SELECT
  t.id_time,
  t.name
FROM
  t_time_table t
ORDER BY
  t.sort DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Будет эффективней

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78fdf8/3)

Comment: Спасибо, не знал о существовании sql Fiddle, взято на заметку.